# Delicious toolbar and https sites

Tags: toolbar, delicious

Sometimes when I navigate to an https site, my delicous toolbar favorite tags disappear from the toolbar.  Any ideas?

[image]

I'm on Vista IE8.  I'd prefer not to change browsers (most of my clients use IE so I feel it's good for me to be on it too.)

Comment: only https sites? or does the symptom appears on normal http sites too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [discussion thread at the delicious support forum](http://support.delicious.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=2151).

Are you sure that you are logged in to Delicious at these times?
Does clicking on the checkered icon open your delicious page?

Since you refer explicitly to `https` page views,
I am wondering if this has something to do with the cookie access.
Its [discussed on this thread](http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-internetexplorer-general/370413-favorites-disappear-when-deleting-cookies.html).